# crontab shell script starts another script: remove char error

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron

I want to run a shell script through crontab which does something and then runs another shell script which checks a certain folder for certain files and creates a directory for each file. 
The first script "my_crontab.sh" looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/myusername/myfolder
python mypythonscript.py
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/home/myusername/myfolder
bash start.sh
```

Crontab executes "my_crontab.sh" and "start.sh" gets also called (I know from the crontab log file)

This is what "start.sh" looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "start.sh started"
if [ $(find -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l) -ne 0 ]; 
then
 for i in *.jpg
 do
  folder="${i/.jpg/}"
  mkdir ../folders/$folder
 done
else
 echo "nothing to do"
fi
```

now I'm getting the error:
    `/bin/sh: 7: /home/myusername/myfolder/start.sh: Bad substitution`

I already tried `folder=${ i:0:-4 }` instead, but that's also not working. 
Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Your script is running with `sh`, and doesn't support bash code like `${i/.jpg/}` (`sh` is to `bash` what C is to C++). You should update `my_crontab.sh` to have `#!/bin/bash`. Updating `start.sh` is not enough. Fix this in addition to the spacing issue mentioned by David C. Rankin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuing from the comment, your `Bad Substitution` in `start.sh` is caused because you are leaving `spaces` in line `7` between the `braces` and your variable name and substitution, (e.g. `"${ i/.jpg/ }"` should be `"${i/.jpg/}"`. Line `4` is problematic because `-ne` expects integer expressions on both sides and there is no guarantee the command substitution will comply (it should with `wc -l`) but it is not guaranteed. You are better served writing `start.sh` something similar to:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "start.sh started"
declare -i cnt=0;

while read -r fname
do
    folder="${fname%.jpg}"
    mkdir -p "../folders/$folder"
    ((cnt++))
done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.jpg")

[ "$cnt" -eq '0' ] && echo "nothing to do"
```

**note:** the counter `cnt` is just used to output `"nothing to do"` in the event there are no `.jpg` files found, if that isn't needed, just delete all lines referring to `cnt`.

Answer (score 0):

ah perfect. thanks a lot!

it also helped to use `bash start.sh` instead of `. start.sh`.

I updated the code above in my question.